# OpenLayers gives 'Uncaught TypeError' in Firefox, but in Edge it works

Tags: javascript, npm, firefox, vite, openlayers

In my JavaScript, I have - among others: `import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';`.

First this worked fine, but for some or another reason Firefox suddenly shows the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “ol/source/OSM” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Note: The example with OSM, but the same error appears with other modules.

In Edge it works fine.

The environment is local, with VITE v3.2.6, started with the command `cmd.exe /k npm start`.